# Show that $Cov(\bar{y},\hat{\beta_1})=0$

Tags: statistics, self-learning

Show that $Cov(\bar{y},\hat{\beta_1})=0$

For those unfamiliar with statistics, Cov(A,B) refers to the covariance function. $\bar{y}$ refers to the average of the response (dependent variable). $\hat{\beta_1}$ refers to the estimator of the slope.

The solution goes as follows:

$Cov(\bar{y},\hat{\beta_1}) = Cov(\frac{\sum{y_i}}{n},\sum{c_iy_i})
$

Where $c_i = \frac{(x_i-\bar{x})}{S_{xx}}
$

And $S_{xx} = \sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

$Cov(\frac{\sum{y_i}}{n},\sum{c_iy_i}) = \frac{1}{n}Cov(\sum{y_i},\sum{c_iy_i})
$

Can we bring the $\sum{c_i}$ out of the covariance? If so, we would simply be left with $var(y_i)$.

Comment: In simple linear regression where the errors are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$, one can show that $\bar y$ and $\hat \beta_1$ are independently distributed Normal variables.

Comment: Indeed, we can use the bilinearity of covariance to write \begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar y,\hat{\beta_1})&=\operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i,\sum_{i=1}^nc_iy_i\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\operatorname{Var}(y_i)
\\&=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i=0
\end{align}

Comment: @StubbornAtom How to show they are independently distributed Normal variables? Can I find such a proof or discussion in George Casella and Berger textbook?

Comment: @Mariana https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/362660/119261.